# Trying to implement Modified Nodal Analysis in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mathjs, circuit-diagram

Im trying to create an educational tool to teach circuits. The student gets asked to create a specfic circuit, draw it in the grid and click test to run modified nodal analysis (MNA) and see if its correct.

I'm struggling with getting the circuitAnalysis.js (the MNA part) working in. I uploaded it all to github here and added some test cases:
https://github.com/jackdaly/electronics-schematic-builder

I'm also having a small issue where its saying I've already added an object (the meter) but its not showing up in the nodeConnectionMap. Its between lines 19 to 24 in circuitAnalysis.js

This is one of my first apps so I would truly apprecaite any feedback on any other aspects. As well as how to best structure questions on stackoverflow - I'm here to learn!

I just cant seem to crack it and there isnt too many papers on how MNA seems to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.